# How can I parallelize this word counting function?

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have some serial code like this that computes word concordances i.e. counting collocated word pairs. The following program works except that the list of sentences is canned for illustrative purposes.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [])))

def BuildConcordance(sentences):
    global GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE
    for sentenceIndex, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        words = [word for word in sentence.split()]

        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            for i, collocate in enumerate(words[index:len(words)]):
                GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE[word][collocate][i].append(sentenceIndex)

def main():
    sentences = ["Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4"]
    BuildConcordance(sentences)
    print GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To me, the first for loop can be parallelized because the numbers being computed are indepedent. However, the data structure being modified is a global one.

I tried using Python's `Pool` module but I am facing some pickling problems which makes me wonder if I am using the right design pattern. Can someone suggest a good way to parallelize this code?

Comment: In the inner-most for loop, you should use `words[index+1:]` instead of `words[index:len(words)]` to avoid adding each word with itself at distance zero every time it appears. (You'll need to use `i+1` instead of `i` inside the loop, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, multiprocessing is easiest when you use a functional style. In this case, my suggestion would be to return a list of result tuples from each instance of the worker function. The extra complexity of the nested `defaultdict`s doesn't really gain you anything. Something like this:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import re

GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))

def concordance_worker(index_sentence):
    sent_index, sentence = index_sentence
    words = sentence.split()

    return [(word, colo_word, colo_index, sent_index)
            for i, word in enumerate(words)
            for colo_index, colo_word in enumerate(words[i:])]

def build_concordance(sentences):
    global GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE
    pool = Pool(8)

    results = pool.map(concordance_worker, enumerate(sentences))

    for result in results:
        for word, colo_word, colo_index, sent_index in result:
            GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE[word][colo_word][colo_index].append(sent_index)

    print len(GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE)


def main():
    sentences = ["Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4"]
    build_concordance(sentences)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let me know if that doesn't generate what you're looking for.

Comment: Why use a global variable? The `build_concordance` function should initialize an empty concordance, fill it up and return it.

Comment: @taleinat, in general I agree. I was just following the OP's example, assuming he had his reasons for using a global.

Comment: Also, just use `words = sentence.split()` in `concordance_worker()`.

Comment: @taleinat, indeed -- I guess that's what I get for copy-and-paste.

Comment: @taleinat: My fault. I substituted nltk's word_tokenize function with the sentence.split() inside and forgot to remove the inline list iteration.

Comment: @senderle: Thank you for your approach. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that parallelizing this calculation will give you any benefit (besides learning about parallelization).

The data structure you are using isn't very efficient in terms of memory usage, because Python dictionaries have a large memory overhead, and you're creating a **lot** of those. Also, you are adding a very large number of items to the "concordance" for each sentence.

I think you should be able to eat up all of your computer's RAM after running this program for just a few minutes on something like a single chapter of a book. This should cause your process to grind to a halt or crash. Have you actually tried running this on a large set of inputs and seeing what happens? If this is the case, it is irrelevant whether or not the computation is done in parallel.

I think you'll need to find a better way of storing the output before parallelization can be of any real benefit. Only turn to parallelization (or other methods of optimization) once you've actually witnessed and diagnosed a problem.

Comment: +1 for your comments. Actually, it wasn't too bad. It did help me quite a bit in reducing the computations to about 2-3 minutes from 15 minutes on a 14 MB dataset. Need to still try it on a 130 MB data set though. However, I am beginning to re-design my solution as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm surprised this worked, 14 MB of text is quite a bit! Perhaps you are filtering most of it away, or perhaps you have just a lot of very short sentences?

I tried this on my post above, and got a concordance with 2,082 items taking up about 240KB of RAM. On a short story of about 400 KB (~90 full pages), I got over 600,000 items in the concordance, taking up over 90 MB of RAM.

This won't scale to anything much larger, certainly not 130 MB of text. Also, building the concordance took just a few seconds.

Comment: Perhaps you are right though I did not see any unusually short sentences. I am rewriting my solution to use a database as I don't really need to store all the concordance information in memory and an index will really be of great help here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too proud of this (looking at the way I converted the defaultdict to avoid pickling errors!!) but here's a solution that works:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import re

def cdefaultdict():
    return []

def bdefaultdict():
    return defaultdict(cdefaultdict)

def adefaultdict():
    return defaultdict(bdefaultdict)

GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE = defaultdict(adefaultdict)

def ConcordanceWorker(work):
    sentenceIndex, sentence = work[0], work[1]
    local_concordance = defaultdict(adefaultdict)
    words = [word for word in sentence.split()]

    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        for i, collocate in enumerate(words[index:len(words)]):
            local_concordance[word][collocate][i].append(sentenceIndex)

    return local_concordance


def BuildConcordance(sentences):
    global GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE
    work = []

    for sentenceIndex, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        work.append([sentenceIndex, sentence])

    pool = Pool(8)

    results = pool.map(ConcordanceWorker, work)

    for result in results:
        for word in result:
            for collocate in result[word]:
                for i in result[word][collocate]:
                    GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE[word][collocate][i] += result[word][collocate][i]

    print len(GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE)


def main():
    sentences = ["Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4"]
    BuildConcordance(sentences)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This may work, but the hack to avoid pickling lambdas is very ugly, you didn't include comments in the code to explain what is going on and why, and you didn't even use `adefaultdict` to initialize GLOBAL_CONCORDANCE.

Comment: @taleinat: Yeap. Deserve the -1 :) Posted this "bad" snippet for reference. Anyways, thanks for pointing them out.