# How to correctly count the occurrences of a given word in a string without counting the word that is a substring of a different word in Python?

Tags: python, split, count

I want to calculate the occurrences of a given word in an article. I tried to use `split` method to cut the articles into n pieces and calculate the length like this.

```
def get_occur(str, word):
    lst = str.split(word)
    return len(lst) - 1
```

But the problem is, I will always count the word additionally if the word is a substring of another word. For example, I only want to count the number of `"sad"` in this sentence `"I am very sad and she is a saddist"`. It should be one, but because "sad" is part of "saddist", I will count it accidentally. If I use `" sad "`, I will omit words that are at the start and end of sentences. Plus, I am dealing with huge number of articles so it is most desirable that I don't have to compare each word. How can I address this? Much appreciated.

Comment: try, ``str_.split().count("sad")``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

def count(text, pattern):
    return len(re.findall(rf"\b{pattern}\b", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

`\b` marks word boundaries and the passed flag makes the matching case insensitive:

```
>>> count("Sadly, the SAD man is sad.", "sad")
2
```

If you want to only count lower-case occurrences, just omit the flag.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @[schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl) in the comment this will miss the word before the comma and there may be other cases so I have updated the answer.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
text = word_tokenize(text)
```

This will give you a list of words. Now use the below code

```
count = 0
for word in text:
 if (word.lower() == 'sad'): # .lower to make it case-insensitive
   count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I am dealing with extremely long articles so the for loop is going to take exceptionally long time... anyway I can do this without affording to compare every word in the articles?

Comment: You can have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016561/how-can-i-parallelize-this-word-counting-function

Comment: @user16256930 The short answer is no. You cannot count occurrences without iterating the entire text, whether that is word by word or letter by letter. All utils you might use like regular expressions that allow to not write a loop yourself will do that iteration under the hood.

Comment: ALso this will not count words before a period or comma.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks. I forgot those extreme cases. I have updated my answer.